# Solve the system (notation submission issues)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Solve the system

$$x_1+x_2+2x_3=3\\
6x_1+7x_2-3x_3=-3$$

---

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    6 & 7 & -3 & -3\\
  \end{bmatrix}\text{~}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    0 & 1 & -15 & -21\\
  \end{bmatrix}\text{~}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 17 & 24\\
    0 & 1 & -15 & -21\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

And using this I found that: 
$$x_1+17x_3=24\\
x_2-15x_3=-21$$

As far as I know this is correct, but my issue is how to state my solution.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1\\
    x_2\\
x_3
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    ?\\
    ?\\
?
  \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    ?\\
    ?\\
?
  \end{bmatrix}s$$

Comment: Just like we did [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288199/describe-all-solutions-of-ax-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that all of your equations have a common factor, namely $x_3$.

Rewrite $x_1$ as a function of $x_3$ and then rewrite $x_2$ as a function of $x_3$. Now by letting $x_3$ vary over your the given field, you'll attain all solutions.

You'll get $x_1=24-17x_3$ and $x_2=-21+15x_3$, so your set of solutions should be $\{ \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{bmatrix}^T : x_1, x_2, x_3\in F \wedge x_1=24-17x_3 \wedge x_2=-21+15x_3\}$ or more succinctly $\{ \begin{bmatrix} 24-17x_3 \space -21+15x_3 \space x_3 \end{bmatrix}^T : x_3\in F\}$, where $F$ is the field you're working on.

In this answer I assumed that your calculations are correct.

For similar problems check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277214/show-two-systems-of-linear-equations-are-equivalent/277224#277224) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278554/solving-matrix-equation-involving-singular-matrix/278564#278564).

EDIT: Your calculations are correct.

Comment: And then to put it in the form OP wants, $$\pmatrix{24-17x_3\cr-21+15x_3\cr x_3\cr}=\pmatrix{24\cr-21\cr0}+\pmatrix{-17\cr15\cr1\cr}x_3$$

Comment: yes, thank you.